# How to switch between tabs with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Here is my use case:

I have a link which on clicking opens a new tab and loads the content.

What I am looking for:

Is there a way to switch the reference of the page while new tab opens or create a reference for the new tab?

Answer (score 4):

To get the page that was opened after a link is clicked, you can listen on the [`popup`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#event-popup) event. It is emitted when the page opens a new tab or window.

**Code sample** (from the docs linked above)

```js
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
    page.click('a[target=_blank]'),
]);
```

This will click on the link while waiting for a window to be opened by the current page. `newPage` will be the opened page.

---

**Alternative approach:** To get a list of all open pages, you can use [`browser.pages`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#browserpages):

```js
const pages = await browser.pages();
```

`pages` will be an array with all open pages.

Answer (score 3):

Use next function:

```js
let clickAndWaitForTarget = async (clickSelector, page, browser) => {
    const pageTarget = page.target(); //save this to know that this was the opener
    await page.click(clickSelector); //click on a link
    const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.opener() === pageTarget); //check that you opened this page, rather than just checking the url
    const newPage = await newTarget.page(); //get the page object
    // await newPage.once("load",()=>{}); //this doesn't work; wait till page is loaded
    await newPage.waitForSelector("body"); //wait for page to be loaded

    return newPage;
};
```

and use it:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('a[href="/admin"]');
page = await clickAndWaitForTarget('a[href="/admin"]', page, browser);

// Admin page
//console.log(JSON.stringify(page.target()));
await page.waitForSelector('a[href="/users"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can follow this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/554 to know when the ability is added to `puppeteer`. Or you can use repo where JoelEinbinder folked

Comment: I was just reading through that issue. I did not see a good example. Could you provide some code on how to follow a new tab using `browser.pages`?

Comment: @Alex you can try with sample below
`const allPages = await browser.pages();
for (var i = 0; i < allPages.length; i++) {
    var tab = allPages[i];
    console.log('tab', tab.url());
}

const hotelPageUrl = allPages[2].url();
`
may you need find your tab index via `for` loop and pass it to next line (`2` in my example)

Comment: Thanks this is helping me debug an issue. Very helpful.