# Switching between tabs in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How to switch between current opened tab to the parent tab using puppeteer?

I have a home page and when i click on the link in home page it opens a new tab. After that page is loading i need to switch to home page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between tabs with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390002/how-to-switch-between-tabs-with-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `browser.pages()` method, it returns a promise which resolves to an array of all open pages.

```
const firstTab = (await browser.pages())[0];
const secondTab = (await browser.pages())[1];
```

Also, you can use `event popup`, emitted when the page opens a new tab or window.

```
const [popup] = await Promise.all([
  new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
  page.click('a[target=_blank]'),
]);

const [popup] = await Promise.all([
 new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
 page.evaluate(() => window.open('https://example.com')),
]);
```

[Read more about events here.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#event-popup)