# How can I switch to a previous tab in a Puppeteer browser instance after opening a new tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jestjs, chromium, puppeteer

### Problem

I'm writing several test suites (using Jest and Puppeteer) to automate tests of my AngularJS app's home page. One of the tests I've written automates the clicking of a button that opens a another website in a new tab. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to force Puppeteer to return to the previous tab (i.e. my app's homepage) after the new tab has been spawned. In other words, for a reason I have yet to discover, Puppeteer seems to get "stuck" on the new tab. It is important for me to be able to switch back to the previous tab so that all the subsequent tests on my app's home page can proceed and pass. So I'm wondering if there's a method that exists in Puppeteer to switch tabs, or at least close a tab so the previous tab will be returned to automatically.

### Overview of my testing environment:

- Puppeteer version: 1.19.0
- Jest version: 24.8.0
- AngularJS version: 1.7.8
- Node.js version: 12.7.0
- Platform / OS version: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

### Broken Code

***Disclaimer:*** In order to provide this community with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I chose not to copy and paste my original code by instead wrote up a simpler example. So I'm sorry in advance for any typos in the following code. I was vigilant but I am human so I make mistakes.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>Check out this cool website:
    <a id="myHyperlink" href="https://example.com" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
// index.spec.js
describe('opens new tab', () => {

  // this test passes
  test('clicks on hyperlink', async() => {
    let hyperlinkSelector = 'a[id="myHyperlink"]';
    await page.click(hyperlinkSelector);
  });

  // this test passes
  test('new tab opened', async() => {
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    const numTabs = (await global.__BROWSER__.pages()).length;
    expect(numTabs).toBe(2);
  });

  // this is the test I'm having trouble with. 
  // I need to find a way to either switch tabs
  // (i.e. return to the previous tab) or close
  // the new tab and return to the previous tab
  test('returns to my app', async() => {

    // attempt 1: I'm aware that the browser object 
    // has a pages method that returns a list of open
    // tabs, but I'm not sure if these tabs are actually clickable
    let tabs = await global.__BROWSER__.pages();
    await page.click(tabs[0]);

    // attempt 2: This doesn't seem to work either
    // and even it if did work, it might not be ideal because obviously
    // waiting for the entire webpage to load again takes a long time
    await page.goto('https://my-website.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    // attempt 3: Get page new tab was opened from and goto it
    const pageTarget = page.target();
    await page.goto(pageTarget.page(), {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  });

});
```

### Current test behavior:

**Attempt 1 result:** The the following error is thrown by Jest and all subsequent tests fail.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
    |     property '_browser' -> object with constructor 'Browser'
    --- property '_defaultContext' closes the circle Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

  635 | 
  636 |     let tabs = await global.__BROWSER__.pages();
> 637 |     await page.click(tabs[0]);
      |                ^
  638 |   });
```

**Attempt 2 result:** The browser never returns to my webpage, so all the subsequent tests that run on my webpage fail.

**Attempt 3 result:** The following error is thrown by Jest and all subsequent tests fail.

```
    Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters url: string value expected

      631 |   test('returns to my app', async() => {
      632 |     const pageTarget = page.target();
    > 633 |     await page.goto(pageTarget.page(), {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
          |           ^
      634 |   });
```

### Expected/desired test behavior:

The `'returns to my app'` test should seamlessly switch the the previous tab so that all my ensuing tests can run and pass.

### Final thoughts/ question:

Do any of you Jest/Puppeteer experts out there know of a way to easily switch tabs/return to a previous tab? *Note:* I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963603/switching-between-tabs-in-puppeteer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390002/how-to-switch-between-tabs-with-puppeteer) on Stack Overflow, but neither of the solutions provided have worked for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's nice you found solution to your problem on your own, and I got to admit, I wish more questions were as detailed and nicely formatted as yours ;)

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the solution to this was very simple. I found it on [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3250).

```
// index.spec.js
test('returns to my app', async() => {
    const tabs = await global.__BROWSER__.pages();
    await tabs[1].close();
});
```